# Load bearing wall above door?

Tags: studs, beam, load

I have a narrow hallway with a doorway right in the middle. I'm trying to get rid of as much of the doorway as possible. I got rid of the trim and this 1/2 inch door frame.... but what's going on in the header is questionable.

There are no jack studs, the whole thing is an insert above the doorway nailed up to the beam.

Is this load bearing? You think I can take it out?

**This is a 30 year old apartment reno. 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

That is not load bearing construction and can be removed. Does that unit have an attic? The beam is at an angle so it's not supporting the floor above. If there is an attic, it's always nice to get up there and check out the construction before knocking out walls.